# Passing a BIT value to a sql server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc(@a nvarchar(50), @b nvarchar(100), @c bit)
AS ...

   SELECT @retVal;
```

I have the following aspx code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("myproc", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", b);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@c", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = false;

SqlParameter returnValue = new SqlParameter("@retVal", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 9999999);
returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(returnValue);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
retVal = (string)cmd.Parameters["@retVal"].Value;   
conn.Close();
```

This gives me the error:

```
Procedure or function myproc has too many arguments specified.
```

If I remove the line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@c", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = false;
```

I get this error:

```
Procedure or function 'myproc' expects parameter '@c', which was not supplied
```

I have tried these alternatives for this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", 0);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", false);
```

How do I pass that BIT parameter?

Comment: Your Stored Procedure doesn't define an output parameter. `@c` isn't your problem, the problem is `@retVal`.

Comment: how do I do that?  I have a SELECT @retVal at the end of the procedure

Comment: I'm assuming your `@retVal` is declared as `@retVal [Data_Type] OUTPUT`? in your sp

Comment: DECLARE @retVal nvarchar(max);

Comment: Why do you have @RequestStatus in code? Surely it's @retVal?

Comment: Stored procedures can only ever return an int. selecting something in an SP is NOT the same as returning a value

Comment: So, how do I get what has been selected?

Comment: Declaring @retval as local variable doesn't make it a parameter that's available outside the proc.

Comment: And let's add the standard admonishment - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I present the 3 ways we can get data out of a procedure:

#### Here is an sp that returns a value

```
CREATE PROCEDURE x AS
BEGIN
  return 1
END
```

You have to get that 1 in your c# by adding a parameter with direction `ReturnValue` and type int (it can only be an int), and reading the parameter `.Value` after you `ExecuteNonQuery`

Typically we use returnvalue to indicate the state of the operation, NOT some data in the table. Eg an AddUser proc that returns 0 for success, 1 for fail because user exists, 2 for fail because password is too weak etc, we wouldn't use returnvalue to return the userid of the newly added user

---

#### Here is an sp that has an output parameter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE x
    @y INT OUTPUT
AS BEGIN
  SET @y = 1
END
```

You have to get that 1 in c# by adding a parameter with name `@y` and direction `Output` and read the parameter value after you `ExecuteNonQuery`. If you use the parameter for input as well, declare the direction as `InputOutput`

---

#### Here is an sp that returns a resultset

```
CREATE PROCEDURE x
AS BEGIN
  SELECT 1 AS y
END
```

You have to get that 1 by doing `ExecuteScalar` or `ExecuteReader`

`ExecuteScalar` returns the top left cell of a resultset; fine for this example. If you plan on returning more rows and columns than just a single value, use `ExecuteReader`

---

It sounds like you're mixing things up; decide how your sp will return its values and code the c# accordingly.

You can mix and match these and have a sproc that has an output parameter, a return value and selects a resultset but you should be clear on which bits of the c# collect what data from which bits of the sproc

Answer (score 2):

Your stored procedure doesn't define an output parameter. `@c` isn't your problem, the problem is `@retVal`.

You need something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc(@a nvarchar(50), @b nvarchar(100), @c bit, @retVal NVARCHAR([LEN]) OUTPUT)
AS...
```

...where `[LEN]` is whatever you need, I doubt it's 9,999,999, but you can do MAX if you want.

Then store `[YOUR RESULT]` in your shiny new output parameter:

```
SELECT @retVal = [YOUR RESULT]
```

...at this point I *believe* your C# code will behave correctly.

Comment: and you need to assign it a value, not "select" it

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Yeah, there wasn't any additional SP code when I wrote this...

Comment: This answer is likely to make things more confusing

Comment: @CaiusJard Story of my life.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this:

```
    returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

to this:

```
    returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

OK, if the `@retVal` is not integer, then you can't use `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`. Stay with `SELECT @retVal`, but change `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` to `var result = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` and also don't define `@retVal` parameter at C#.